# Should optional Foreign Key be NULL or should it point to an empty string

Tags: django, database, django-models

When the related value in foreign table is missing for an optional `Foreign Key`, I can either:

1. Set it to `null`
2. Point it to an empty string `''` in the foreign table

It appears to me that if you follow Django design practices, you end up with option `2` (see code below). Is there any obvious advantage or downside with either approach?

Django favors `2` somewhat by design/convention. The docs say that `null` and `''` are 2 possible values of "no-data". Hence if you omit the optional field, the forms will validate correctly and supply an empty string to which your `Foreign Key` can point to. 
However logically, it seems like a missing value should imply a `null` or missing `Foreign Key` (instead of a valid `Foreign Key` that points to an empty value).

Moreover, storing blank would be a gotcha if I simply list all albums or do a count. Each time I've to remember to avoid the empty string. On the contrary, a `null` foreign key would never have an entry in the album table.

Reference:

1. [Can a foreign key be NULL...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7574042/4150760)
2. [Can foreign key be NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024190/4150760)
3. Django docs on [null vs blank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#null)

---

Optional detail with code:

```
#models.py
class Album(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Song(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50) 
    album = ForeignKey(Album, null=True, blank=True)    

#forms.py
class SongForm(Form):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    album = CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
```

If you have a song with no album name, the form returns `{'name':'foo', 'album':''}`. This creates an entry in `Album` table with a blank name. I can circumvent that in the view (see code below). But this seems like a hack since data validation should be done in forms.

```
if album:
    Song.objects.create(name=form.cleaned_data['name'], album=form.cleaned_data['album'])
else:
    Song.objects.create(name=form.cleaned_data['name'], album_id=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking more, approach `2` (the one in which a missing foreign relation implies an `FK` to an empty string) has one advantage compared to approach `1`.

Using approach `2`would make it easier to have a `unique_together` index on `(song.name, song.album)`. This is better explained with an example. When empty strings are used for `Album`, two similar values of `Song` (`d` below) would be caught by unique constraint. However, `null` are treated as different values in DB and they won't be caught in case 1 (have to rely on conditional indexes to make this work).

I'm not sure this was by design or an accidental advantage of Django's convention.

```
Missing album => FK is null                    Missing Album => FK points to blank name
Song  |   Album                                Song  |   Album
----------------                               ----------------
'a'   |    'x'                                 'a'   |    'x' 
'b'   |    'y'                                 'b'   |    'y'
'c'   |    'y'                                 'c'   |    'y'
'd'   |    null                                'd'   |    ''
'd'   |    null  <- Dup. not caught by DB      'd'   |    ''   <- Duplicate caught by DB
```

Answer (score 0):

Django's convention is to use `''` to represent the lack of data in text-based fields. When it comes to `ForeignKeys`, however, the convention in Django and elsewhere is to represent the lack of data by `NULL` (i.e. option 1).

Your option 2 confuses the distinction between *an album with no name* and *a song with no album*. Django's convention has to do with different ways to represent the lack of data in a field where that is allowed. But in your case, it is *not* valid to have an album with no name, so option 2 would require inventing a invalid album just to give other models something to point to.

You write: "Point it to an empty string `''` in the foreign table". Note, though, that foreign keys don't point to fields in a foreign table, they point to entire rows. Imagine you had other fields in the `Album` model (a `BooleanField` `is_international`, for example, or a `DateField` `release_date`). Now you have to make up arbitrary, fake values for these fields in your magical row that doesn't represent an actual album.

So I suggest sticking with the conventional option 1.

Handling this in forms is built-in and straightforward. In `ModelForms`, for example, a `ForeignKey` is represented by a `ModelChoiceField`. If the `ForeignKey` has `blank=True` and `null=True` then one of the choices in the dropdown will be blank, and saving the form with that choice selected will make the corresponding database field `NULL`.

In your case it looks like you're having the user enter the album name directly on the `Song` form. That's perfectly fine, but of course you're going to have to have special logic to interpret that value and create the appropriate models. Your sample code above is not a hack and is not data validation. Validation is *allowing* empty values or not, and that is controlled by `blank=True` (in the model) or `required=False` (in the form).

Comment: Can you cite a doc/example or show in the above code, how would Django represent `FK` by `null` with validation in forms. Regarding `2`, I agree with you in principle, but if I were to argue solely based on Django docs, I'd say to represent "no-data" `Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL`. By this logic, 'no name' is not an invalid album name, rather it signifies missing data. Lastly, by "point to an empty string", I know `FK` points to a row and not to a field. Also see my answer below.

Comment: The convention you're quoting relates to text-based fields ("Avoid using null on string-based fields such as `CharField` and `TextField`..."). It is the exception to the usual rule that `NULL` represents the lack of data in a field. That includes `ForeignKeys`. I edited the answer to address your comment about forms. If you're having a specific problem getting something to work I suggest asking a new question.

Comment: I understand that convention is for text fields but that's the closest Django gets on any discussion about `null` values in general. I am unable to use ModelFields in my app. I feel that the convention on optional `FK` is a grey area in Django.